# Periodic action within Java stream / forEach when iterating a collection

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

In old days Java, we can loop a collection and every `X` items do a certain action - for example, save to DB a bulk of items:

So given

```
List students = ....;
```

We can do some periodic actions - something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
    methodA(students.get(i));
    methodB(students.get(i));

    if (i % 100 == 0){
        flushToDB(...);
        reportProgressToSlack(...);
        ....
    }
}
```

When trying to do something similar using `Streams` we get an error:

```
int counter = 0;
students.stream().forEach(student -> {
    methodA(student);
    methodB(student);
    counter++;
});
```

But of course, the compiler complains about `counter` that must be final or effective final.

Is there a way to do such a thing using java `Streams`?

Comment: Note that you are not using a stream in your code.

Comment: In current Java days you can also loop a collection and do whatever every X items. Java Stream API just provide you with extra tools but nothing prevents you to use the most suitable iteration strategy for each case. Since what you want to do could be somewhat complex maybe it will be more readable with regular ol' times for loop.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on the other answers, using a filter to pass through every 100th entry. First by streaming the list index:

```java
IntStream.range(0, students.size()).filter(i -> {
    Student student = students.get(i);
    methodA(student);
    methodB(student);
    return i % 100 == 0;
}).forEach(...);
```

Second, by streaming and tracking the accumulated index:

```java
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
students.stream().filter(student -> {
    methodA(student);
    methodB(student);
    return i.getAndIncrement() % 100 == 0;
}).forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

A replica of your for-loop using the stream API can look like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, students.size())
     .forEach(i -> {
        methodA(students.get(i));
        methodB(students.get(i));

        if (i % 100 == 0){
            flushToDB(...);
            reportProgressToSlack(...);
            ....
        }
     });
```

With a warning that the pipeline above must remain sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach:

```java
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
students.forEach(student -> {
    methodA(student);
    methodB(student);
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() % 100 == 0) {
        flushToDB(...);
        reportProgressToSlack(...);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) wrapper for such cases:

```
List students = ....;
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
students.forEach(student -> {
    methodA(student);
    methodB(student);
    counter.getAndIncrement();
});
```